# fill a polygon , list out of range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to fill a polygon from a csv file, i am using the following code and a problem occured in line `y.append(str(row[1]))`

> IndexError: list index out of range"

**Code:**

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import csv

    x = []
    y = []
    # coord = [[1,1], [2,1], [2,2], [1,2],]
    with open('screen.txt','r') as csvfile:
        coord = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in coord:
            x.append(str(row[0]))
            y.append(str(row[1]))

    coord.append(coord[0]) #repeat the first point to create a 'closed loop'

    xs, ys = zip(*coord) #create lists of x and y values

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(xs,ys)
    plt.fill(xs, ys, color= "r")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: The problem may lie in your csv file. Are you sure the values are comma separated?

Comment: yes, it is separted by comma

Comment: What is the content of the csv file?

Comment: thanks , the problem was with the file ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question supposes that file 'screen.txt' looks like:

```
1,1
2,1
2,2
1,2
```

Then, you create a variable `coords`, which is a `_csv.reader object` while the subsequent code behaves as if `coords` were a simple list. The reader object is a special object that reads a file, and permits constructions as `for row in coords`. But it only reads parts of the file while needed (to prevent cases such as reading millions of lines while you only need a few). After you close the file (i.e. after the `with open(...`) the reader object gets unusable.

As simple workaround, and in case the file is not extremely long, you can convert the coords to a list: `coords = list(coords)`. And from then on, it can be used as a normal list.

By the way, if the file is like described above, the error `list index out of range` would be thrown for the line `coord.append(coord[0])`.

Another possible cause could be that your input-file contains empty lines at the end. Then you would get the first error at `x.append(str(row[0]))` or `y.append(str(row[1]))` if the last line just contains a few spaces. But after deleting the empty lines, you would still get an error at `coord.append(coord[0])`

The adapted code (leaving out the lists x and y as they are not really used in this version):

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# coord = [[1,1], [2,1], [2,2], [1,2],]
with open('screen.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    coord = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    coord = list(coord)  # we can step out of the 'with', because the file isn't needed
                         # anymore once we have the real list

coord.append(coord[0])  # repeat the first point to create a 'closed loop'
xs, ys = zip(*coord)    # create lists of x and y values

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.fill(xs, ys, color="r")
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal') # needed so squares look square, x and y axis get the same pixels per unit
plt.show()
```

Which displays a nice square:
[image: the plotted square]
PS: The above version stores the coordinates as strings, while it might be more efficient to directly work with numbers.

A better and more readable version (suggested by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest):

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
# coord = [[1,1], [2,1], [2,2], [1,2],]
with open('screen.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    coord = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in coord:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))
x.append(x[0])
y.append(y[0])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.fill(x, y, color="orchid")
plt.show()
```